# Yii: google map api(Place Autocomplete and Directions ) not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, yii

Hi i am a yiibie and i am trying to implement `Place Autocomplete and Directions(google map Api)`, for that i have obtained the google map Api and have also enabled `Google Maps Directions API, Google Maps JavaScript API, Google Places API Web Service`. When i implement the given code in my view file (which i have copied from here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions) and run my project only a small part of the map appears on my screen for few seconds and then disappears. What could be the problem, here is the code of my view file.

```
<?php
/* @var $this NgoController */
/* @var $model Ngo */
/* @var $form BSActiveForm */
?>

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.BsActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'ngo-form',
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <p class="help-block">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'ngo_name',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'email',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'address',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'image',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>

    <!--code for map starts here-->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#origin-input,
#destination-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 200px;
}

#origin-input:focus,
#destination-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#mode-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}

#mode-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}


    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="origin-input" class="controls" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter an origin location">

    <input id="destination-input" class="controls" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a destination location">

    <div id="mode-selector" class="controls">
      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-walking" checked="checked">
      <label for="changemode-walking">Walking</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-transit">
      <label for="changemode-transit">Transit</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-driving">
      <label for="changemode-driving">Driving</label>
    </div>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
function initMap() {
  var origin_place_id = null;
  var destination_place_id = null;
  var travel_mode = google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeControl: false,
    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    zoom: 13
  });
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  var origin_input = document.getElementById('origin-input');
  var destination_input = document.getElementById('destination-input');
  var modes = document.getElementById('mode-selector');

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(origin_input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destination_input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(modes);

  var origin_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(origin_input);
  origin_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
  var destination_autocomplete =
      new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destination_input);
  destination_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
  // Autocomplete.
  function setupClickListener(id, mode) {
    var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
    radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      travel_mode = mode;
    });
  }
  setupClickListener('changemode-walking', google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING);
  setupClickListener('changemode-transit', google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT);
  setupClickListener('changemode-driving', google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING);

  function expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place) {
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);
    }
  }

  origin_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = origin_autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
      return;
    }
    expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);

    // If the place has a geometry, store its place ID and route if we have
    // the other place ID
    origin_place_id = place.place_id;
    route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
          directionsService, directionsDisplay);
  });

  destination_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = destination_autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
      return;
    }
    expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);

    // If the place has a geometry, store its place ID and route if we have
    // the other place ID
    destination_place_id = place.place_id;
    route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
          directionsService, directionsDisplay);
  });

  function route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
                 directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    if (!origin_place_id || !destination_place_id) {
      return;
    }
    directionsService.route({
      origin: {'placeId': origin_place_id},
      destination: {'placeId': destination_place_id},
      travelMode: travel_mode
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
}

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAtvEXUyjEkGlAVhwVm9Nr-hCrW2L2MkmU&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>



    <?php echo BsHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('color' => BsHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_PRIMARY)); ?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html alone work fine (the map is show) but your php code cointain tag outside the html.  Try move this part of code inside the body section 
like this eg:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Place Autocomplete</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
          #map {
            height: 100%;
          }
    .controls {
      margin-top: 10px;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      height: 32px;
      outline: none;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

    #origin-input,
    #destination-input {
      background-color: #fff;
      font-family: Roboto;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: 300;
      margin-left: 12px;
      padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      width: 200px;
    }

    #origin-input:focus,
    #destination-input:focus {
      border-color: #4d90fe;
    }

    #mode-selector {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #4d90fe;
      margin-left: 12px;
      padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
    }

    #mode-selector label {
      font-family: Roboto;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: 300;
    }


        </style>
      </head>
      <body>

    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.BsActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'ngo-form',
        // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
        // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
        // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
        // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    )); ?>

        <p class="help-block">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

        <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

        <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'ngo_name',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'email',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'address',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'image',array('maxlength'=>45)); ?>

    <?php echo BsHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('color' => BsHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_PRIMARY)); ?>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

        <input id="origin-input" class="controls" type="text"
            placeholder="Enter an origin location">

        <input id="destination-input" class="controls" type="text"
            placeholder="Enter a destination location">

        <div id="mode-selector" class="controls">
          <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-walking" checked="checked">
          <label for="changemode-walking">Walking</label>

          <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-transit">
          <label for="changemode-transit">Transit</label>

          <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-driving">
          <label for="changemode-driving">Driving</label>
        </div>

        <div id="map"></div>

        <script>
    function initMap() {
      var origin_place_id = null;
      var destination_place_id = null;
      var travel_mode = google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING;
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        mapTypeControl: false,
        center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
        zoom: 13
      });
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
      var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

      var origin_input = document.getElementById('origin-input');
      var destination_input = document.getElementById('destination-input');
      var modes = document.getElementById('mode-selector');

      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(origin_input);
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destination_input);
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(modes);

      var origin_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(origin_input);
      origin_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
      var destination_autocomplete =
          new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destination_input);
      destination_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

      // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
      // Autocomplete.
      function setupClickListener(id, mode) {
        var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
        radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
          travel_mode = mode;
        });
      }
      setupClickListener('changemode-walking', google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING);
      setupClickListener('changemode-transit', google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT);
      setupClickListener('changemode-driving', google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING);

      function expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place) {
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
          map.setZoom(17);
        }
      }

      origin_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        var place = origin_autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
          window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
          return;
        }
        expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);

        // If the place has a geometry, store its place ID and route if we have
        // the other place ID
        origin_place_id = place.place_id;
        route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
              directionsService, directionsDisplay);
      });

      destination_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        var place = destination_autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
          window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
          return;
        }
        expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);

        // If the place has a geometry, store its place ID and route if we have
        // the other place ID
        destination_place_id = place.place_id;
        route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
              directionsService, directionsDisplay);
      });

      function route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, travel_mode,
                     directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        if (!origin_place_id || !destination_place_id) {
          return;
        }
        directionsService.route({
          origin: {'placeId': origin_place_id},
          destination: {'placeId': destination_place_id},
          travelMode: travel_mode
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    }

        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAtvEXUyjEkGlAVhwVm9Nr-hCrW2L2MkmU&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: still not working, i also the html alone but it gives the same output.

Comment: I have tried the html alone and the maps show correctly. for the rest I  can't test..